# How to access the grid data using selenium webdriver

Tags: automated-testing

I have application which uses grid to display the details. using selenium web driver how can I access the data present in the grid.Following is the html code

```
<div id="contenttable_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamGrid" height="100%" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 1225.3px; margin-left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<div id="contenttable_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamGrid" height="100%" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 1225.3px; margin-left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<div id="row0_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamGrid" style="position: relative; height: 28px;" role="row">
<div id="row1_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamGrid" style="position: relative; height: 28px;" role="row">
<div id="row2_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamGrid" style="position: relative; height: 28px;" role="row">
<div id="row3_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamGrid" style="position: relative; height: 28px;" role="row">
<div id="row4_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamGrid" style="position: relative; height: 25px;" role="row">
<div id="row5_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamGrid" style="position: relative; height: 25px;" role="row">
<div id="row6_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamGrid" style="position: relative; height: 25px;" role="row">
<div id="row7_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamGrid" style="position: relative; height: 25px;" role="row">
<div id="row8_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamGrid" style="position: relative; height: 25px;" role="row">
<div id="row9_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamGrid" style="position: relative; height: 25px;" role="row">
</div>
```

My code:

```
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver(); 
driver.get(Configuration.HelpGuideHomePage.baseURL);
AppFunctions.authorizedUserLogin(driver, TestData.sEmailAddress, TestData.sPassword); 
Thread.sleep(3000); 
AppFunctions.clickTeam(driver); 
Thread.sleep(3000); //click on check boxes WebElement  
element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='jqx-checkbox-default jqx-fill-state-normal jqx-rc-all']")); 
element.click();
```

Comment: What have you already tried?  Are you getting an error?  I think people will need more background to assist you in this case.

Comment: Add the code you have so far. Also, I don't see any data in the DIV elements?

Comment: <div class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item jqx-grid-cell-wrap jqx-grid-cell-alt" style="left: 30px; z-index: 792; width:703.2999996px;" role="gridcell">
<div style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; padding-bottom: 2px; text-align: left; margin-right: 2px; margin-left: 4px; margin-top: 5px;">Basic Temp-Scenario Model Team</div>
</div>

Comment: Basic Temp-Scenario Model Team....This is data which is present in second row of the grid

Comment: I have to access this data using selenium web driver.WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get(Configuration.HelpGuideHomePage.baseURL);
  AppFunctions.authorizedUserLogin(driver, TestData.sEmailAddress, TestData.sPassword);
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  AppFunctions.clickTeam(driver);
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  //click on check boxes
  WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='jqx-checkbox-default jqx-fill-state-normal jqx-rc-all']"));
  element.click();

Comment: Using java I have to access the grid

Comment: I didnt find any code to access the data in the grid. canany one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get access to the text of an element you use:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("row0_TeamManagement_WAR_TeamManagementportlet_teamGrid"));
String elementText = element.getText();
System.out.println(elementText);
```